# Market with substitutes: Response of prices and quantities

Tags: microeconomics, supply-and-demand

The demand function for theater tickets is $D_t(p_t,p_c)$, where $p_t$ stands for the price of theater tickets and $p_c$ stands for the price of cinema tickets. Supply of theater tickets is described by $S_t(p_t)$. I want to determine how the equilibrium price and quantity of theater tickets changes if the price of movie tickets changes from $p_c$ to $p'_c$. I just have to solve the equations
$$
D_t(p_t,p_c) = S_t(p_t)
$$
and
$$
D_t(p'_t,p'_c) = S_t(p'_t)
$$
right?

Comment: Please see our policy for homework questions: http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/q/1465/42

Comment: @Chris L I generalized the question to make it compatible with our policy. If you disagree you can roll back the edit to yours.

Comment: I like the question much more this way, and would vote to keep it open.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this question in this form though, since it just seems to be, "yes."